# Data binning with error bars

Tags: uncertainty, binning

I've got some measured data where each data point has an uncertainty associated with it i.e,

Data $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ with uncertainties $\mathbf{\alpha}_x = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n)$.

Due to the density of the number of data points, I'd like to bin these points. For example, combine every 4 points into a single point. IIRC, this process can also improve the confidence on the measured statistic as a result. So if I had 1000 data points with 1000 uncertainties, I could bin the data by a ratio of 4:1 and end up with 250 data points with 250 uncertainties, with a higher degree of confidence in those 250 points.

How exactly is this performed and could I have a reference please?

Many thanks